# How to return a single character as a string type?

Tags: java, string, character

So I'm working on a homework project and there's a point where I'm required to place a letter grade into a double array of a string type. So I wrote a block of code to take an input "score" of type double and return a letter grade of type string. But Eclipse is telling me I have an error and need to return type string. I don't understand what my problem is.

```
public static String getLetterGrade(double score) {
    if (90 >= score && score <= 100)
        return "A";

    if (80 >= score && score < 90)
        return "B";

    if (70 >= score && score < 80)
        return "C";

    if (60 >= score && score < 70)
        return "D";

    if (score < 60)
        return "F";
} //end of getLetterGrade()
```

Comment: You need the **else** part. for that you have to return a default value in the end of your method

Comment: You need to return something in case nothing matches.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the issue.

Comment: "*I'm required to place a letter grade into a double array of a string type*" - Do you possibly mean a 2D-array? A "double array" is more likely to be interpreted as `double[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need return something by default, you don't need to check the last condition.

```
public static String getLetterGrade(double score) {
    if (90 >= score && score <= 100)
        return "A";

    if (80 >= score && score < 90)
        return "B";

    if (70 >= score && score < 80)
        return "C";

    if (60 >= score && score < 70)
        return "D";

    if (score > 100)
        return "Error";

    return "F";
}
```

Comment: this can return `F` if `score` is greet than `100`

Comment: "*... you don't need to check the last condition.*" - I dare to object. It woudl be cleaner to throw some kind of `Exception` if the score is something unexpected, e.g. negative or greater than 100.

Comment: that's correct, edited to know if score is greater than 100.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a value or throw an exception, i'd prefer to throw an exception in case of invalid input, alternatively you can return a string which represents invalid input; or null.

```
public static String getLetterGrade(double score) throws Exception{
    if (90 >= score && score <= 100)
        return "A";

    if (80 >= score && score < 90)
        return "B";

    if (70 >= score && score < 80)
        return "C";

    if (60 >= score && score < 70)
        return "D";

    if (score < 60)
        return "F";

    throw new Exception("Invalid score");
}
```

Comment: Don' throw some unspecific `Exception`. Either create your own, e.g. `IllegalScoreException`, or throw an existing exception, e.g. `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: I totally agree, exceptions should always be specific, this answer was just to point out the problem in the code.